# Group/aggregate data in ag grid

Tags: react-typescript, ag-grid-react

I have data which contains country, state, city and population. Basically i am looking for a table view using ag grid in which i just want to group all the columns if country is USA. For rest table should show the data as it is?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.